# Azure Linux Web App Default Page Isn't getting replaced

Tags: azure, web-deployment, asp.net-core-2.2

I've deployed an asp.net core 2.2 webapp to azure linux appservice using VS2019 deployment.

It was successful, but my front page is still Default Azure Page, and none of the controllers are working.

What am I missing?

I get the same result by running devops build/release.

I had to set environment variable WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM = false to be able to deploy the app.
I tried looking for Default Documents page on azure to remove the default page, but the azure page for it is gone.

I FTP'ed onto server, my app is there, there is no sign of any default.html.

How do I get my site to actually run and display after deployment success?

Comment: Maybe you deploy the app to one deployment slot but try to browse it in another one?

Comment: hi, did you found any root cause of that problem?..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59737998/6576267 Yes, you need to run a start command for Linux app. Until you start the program, the page will just show default windows app page.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check the **Startup Command** in your Azure App Service configuration settings.
Replace

> YourApp.dll

with your applications dll name.

[image]